# How do I set the result schema in a Doctrine query?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to create a JSON customer API for a frontend and I am using Symfony with Doctrine for that. In the customer repository there are the following code:

```
public function getCustomerById($customerId) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->andWhere('c.customerId = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $customerId)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

With that code I get an array with all columns of my customer entity or table. Also I have two ManyToOne relations e.g. user. The query above also selects ALL columns from that user table an put the data in an extra key which is exactly what I want but not all columns, e.g. I don't want the password in the result. So is there an easy way to specify which columns it should query ONLY from the joined table or do I need to select ALL columns from customer AND user that I want?

If I try the latter with specified columns in the result all columns are in one level in the array (user data not hydrated under an extra key).

The expected result/array schould be:

```
...
firstName: '',
lastName: '',
user: 
    userId: 1,
    userName: '',
creationDate: '',
...
```

How can I get such a result and hydrate joined table columns in an extra key like user above without extra data mapping from one array to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the above result when I use partial select

```
SELECT partial c.{customerId, ...}, partial u.{userId, userName} ...
```

Nevertheless it returns an array with all columns but those which are not selected are null. With using hydation mode HYDRATE_ARRAY they are gone.

Comment: you might try `->getArrayResult()` instead.